# Unity Player character is not moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development

I have a script to move my character(Player) in unity. The script is fine and it does not have any errors, Although when i enter
play mode and try to use the arrows to move my character, it does not move at all, i can't figure out what is the problem.

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{ 
   public float moveSpeed = 1f;
   public float CollisionOffset = 0.05f;
   public ContactFilter2D movementFilter; 

    Vector2 movementInput;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    List<RaycastHit2D> castCollisions = new List<RaycastHit2D>();

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
      rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate() {
        if (movementInput != Vector2.zero) {
           int count = rb.Cast(
            movementInput,
            movementFilter,
            castCollisions,
            moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime + CollisionOffset
           );

           if (count == 0) {
            rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movementInput * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
           }
        }
    }

    void onMove(InputValue movementValue) {
       movementInput = movementValue.Get<Vector2>();
    }
}
```

Unity version: 2022.2.0b14

Input System: version 1.2.0

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The "onMove" method when it gets executed, because from what I see your movementInput it will be equal Vector2.Zero because when you create the refference it will automatically be Zero.

Comment: @PavlosMavris could you please elaborate?

Comment: Your "movementInput" will be Zero unless your "onMove" method executes. I suppose your onMove method will execute when your player starts moving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OnMove not executing because it's OnMove not onMove. this is reference directly by new input system. So the Function name should be On+[ActionName] and here when you are using Default InputActions so Move -> OnMove.